# How to Select columns from tow different table(A,B) where sum(column tableA) less then columntableB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I can select price where sum(tax) less than price, I am executing the Query but I am getting an error

```
select    b.price
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on b.idprice = a.idprice where sum(tax)<price
group by a.idprice,b.price
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Could you post the schema as well? The query you are attempting, and the error you are receiving would help a lot. Perhaps you can reproduce it using http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference. my erorr

Comment: select b.price
from tabelA a
inner join
  tabelB b on b.idprice = a.idprice where sum(a.tax)<b.idprice
 group by a.idprice,b.price ..... my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your original approach will work by using a `having` clause rather than a `where`:

```
select b.price
from tableA a inner join
     tableB b
     on b.idprice = a.idprice
group by a.idprice, b.price
having sum(tax) < b.price;
```

Answer (score 2):

so something like this:

```
SELECT t.*,s.*
FROM TableA t
INNER JOIN(SELECT idprice,sum(tax) as sum_tax
           FROM TableB
           GROUP BY idprice) s
ON(t.idprice = s.idprice and t.price < s.sum_tax)
```

Or if price table should be summed too :

```
SELECT t.idprice,sum(t.price),max(s.sum_tax)
FROM TableA t
INNER JOIN(SELECT idprice,sum(tax) as sum_tax
           FROM TableB
           GROUP BY idprice) s
ON(t.idprice = s.idprice)
GROUP BY t.idprice
having sum(t.price) < max(s.sum_tax)
```

Comment: but invalid (tax , t.price in your query

Comment: this error from your query   (Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'tax'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'price'.)

Comment: So change it to your column names. I am not a magician and I cant guess them, try to work too. @saman

Comment: thank you , your query is true, i am slip-up in column name , thank you for help